# combine/merge two csv using pandas/python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have two csvs, I want to combine or merge these csvs as left join...
my key column is "id", I have same non-key column as "result" in both csvs, but I want to override "result" column if any value exists in "result" column of 2nd CSV . How can I achieve that using pandas or any scripting lang. Please see my final expected output.

### Input

**input.csv:**

```
id,scenario,data1,data2,result
1,s1,300,400,"{s1,not added}"
2,s2,500,101,"{s2 added}"
3,s3,600,202,
```

**output.csv:**

```
id,result
1,"{s1,added}"
3,"{s3,added}"
```

### Expected Output

**final_output.csv**

```
id,scenario,data1,data2,result
1,s1,300,400,"{s1,added}"
2,s2,500,101,"{s2 added}"
3,s3,600,202,"{s3,added}"
```

### Current Code:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("output.csv")
merged = a.merge(b, on='test_id',how='left')
merged.to_csv("final_output.csv", index=False)
```

### Question:

Using this code I am getting the result column twice. I want only once and it should override if value exists in that column.  How do I get a single result column?

Comment: You want this in `python` or a code in `awk` is acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, this works as well

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
c=pd.merge(a,b,on='id',how='left')
lst=[]
for i in c.index:
    if(c.iloc[i]['result_x']!=''):
         lst.append(c.iloc[i]['result_x'])
    else:
         lst.append(c.iloc[i]['result_y'])
c['result']=pd.Series(lst)
del c['result_x']
del c['result_y']
```

Comment: Hey @Mahesh,
I modified a code little bit... As I wanted all the data from right csv "result column" if exists.

`for i in c.index:

    if(pd.isnull(c.iloc[i]['result_y'])):

         lst.append(c.iloc[i]['result_x'])    
    else:
         lst.append(c.iloc[i]['result_y'])`

Comment: @Madhura Mhatre ok...you got the desired result right?

Answer (score 1):

This will combine the columns as desired:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("output.csv")
merged = a.merge(b, on='id', how='outer')

def merge_results(row):
    y = row['result_y']
    return row['result_x'] if isinstance(y, float) else y

merged['result'] = merged.apply(merge_results, axis=1)
del merged['result_x']
del merged['result_y']

merged.to_csv("final_output.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) as below.

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("output.csv")
frames=[a,b]
mergedFrames=pd.DataFrame()
mergedFrames=pd.concat(frames, sort=True)
mergedFrames.to_csv(path/to/location)
```

NOTE: The `sort=True` is added to avoid some warnings