# How to merge several CSV files into one dataframe using pandas on unique column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

I have several csv files that share one column in common: "unique_id". I want to merge all the csv files into one csv file using pandas. Each file does not have the same number of rows. I want to have the output csv file have unique columns. It's fine if the merged file contains missing values. I am really confused on how to do this. An example of what I want is below:

```
csv1:
unique_id      date_of_birth      registered  
15ab           11/2/1990          Yes  
19qz           10/3/1980          No  
20b3                              Yes  
11b9a          3/18/1943  
4r2p                              No  
12p3           8/17/2003  

csv2:  
unique_id      fav_color     parents_alive  
15ab           blue          yes  
19qz           green         yes                              
11b9a                        no                  
12p3           pink    
79b2b2         red

csv3:  
unique_id     married       years_of_education   
15ab          Yes           8  
19qz          No            12  
79b2b2        Yes           6
2224b                       5  
100qwe3       Yes  
333o4         Yes           16    

Output csv:  
unique_id    date_of_birth    registered    fav_color    parents_alive    married    years_of_education
15ab         11/2/1990        Yes           blue         yes              Yes        8
19qz         10/3/1980        No            green        yes              No         12
20b3                          Yes
11b9a        3/18/1943                                   no
4r2p                          No
12p3         8/17/2003                      pink
79b2b2                                      red                           Yes        6
2224b                                                                                5
100qwe3                                                                   Yes
333o4                                                                     Yes        16
```

Comment: Wouldn't [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) do it?

Comment: easy if you can use pandas, how to [read csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), how to [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) dataframes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [combine/merge two csv using pandas/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669299/combine-merge-two-csv-using-pandas-python)